# OS X Yosemite - iPython only acessible with sudo

Tags: python, ipython, osx-yosemite

I had iPython installed on older versions of OS X. Recently I've upgraded for OS X Yosemite and I'm not being able to use iPhyton without sudo permission:

```
$ ipython
-bash: /usr/local/share/python/ipython: No such file or directory
```

However if I use sudo it works. I've installed it though pip.

How can I give to all users access to iPython?

Comment: did you try reinstalling or did you install after the upgrade?

Comment: I got iPython on OSX Yosemite through [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/). This includes a lot of powerful and useful modules

Comment: Also what does `which -a ipython` output?

Comment: hello Padraic `$ which -a python` is returning `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`
`/usr/local/bin/python`
`/usr/bin/python`
that's weird, I apparently have three different installations